# Modifying Page-Links <!--nextpage--> format

Tags: functions, pagination, nextpage

I'm developing a mobile theme and need to change the format of posts that are using the  tag.

Can I add something to functions.php to change the format?

Ideally i'd like to make each page a list-item then display all inline on one page versus an individual pages, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to alter the global variables related to paging after calling `the_post()` in your loop.

```
global $post, $pages, $numpages, $multipage;
while( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    if( is_mobile() ) {
        $pages = array( $post->post_content );
        $page = $numpages = 1;
        $multipage = false;
    }

    // ... template
    the_content();
}
```

Basically what you're doing is un-doing the paging setup done in [`setup_postdata()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/query.php#L3589)